# Compare dates and logs in a formatted bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

In this script I do have to:

1) print current date

2) print the date of the last modified log file

3) if current date is equal to the log1 and log2 mod. date, count lines of log1, log2

4) if current date is equal to the log1 and log2 mod. date, sum their lines (`wc` log1 + `wc` log2)

5) if sum of lines of log1 and log2 is > 100,

```
exit 2
```

6) if current date and date of last mod. of log1 and log2 are different, set line count of log1 at 0 and line count of log2 at 0.

Here is my script, so far. If you want to test it, save this .sh script in you home, and create in your home directory a non empty `log_1.log` file and a non empty `log_2.log` file.

There are syntax errors from line 29.

```
#!/bin/bash

#current date
printf "Current date:\n"

current_date=$(date +'%d  %B' | cut -c1-7) # 

echo $current_date #  

###########################################################

printf "Last modify date of log 1:\n"

date_log_1=$(ls -oF log_1.log | gawk '{print $6" ", $5'})

echo $date_log_1

printf "Last modify date of log 2:\n"

date_log_2=$(ls -oF log_2.log | gawk '{print $6 " ", $5'})

echo $date_log_2

if [[ $current_date == $date_log_1 ]]; then  
    count_line1=$(wc -l log_1.log)  
    printf "log 1 lines are \n $count_line1 \n"  

# sum count lines 
sum=$(("$count_line1 + $count_line2"))

fi #end

if [[ $current_date == $date_log_2 ]]; then  
    count_line2=$(wc -l ciao2.log)  
    printf "log 2 lines are \n $count_line2 \n"  

sum=$(($count_line1 + $count_line2))

fi

# is sum > 100?
if [[ sum > 100 ]]; 
then
    exit 2;
fi

###########################################################

if [[ $current_date != $date_log_1 ]]; then
    # set line count at 0       
    echo -n "" > log_1.log # set word count at 0
fi

if [[ $current_date != $date_log_2 ]]; then
    # set line count at 0       
    echo -n "" > log_2.log # set word count at 0
fi
```

Comment: You should add which error you are getting, which I guess is `log_1.log + : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".log + ")` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I guess there are also logic errors hidden, so I would be happy if an experienced bash user could help me with this script. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, this is not how StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "Here's a bunch of my code, please debug it for me" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask] for more information. A good place to start with your problem is https://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to fix this line

```
date_log_1=$(ls -oF log_1.log | gawk '{print $6" ", $5'})
```

to

```
date_log_1=$(ls -oF log_1.log | gawk '{print $6" ", $5}')
```

(And a similar line slightly below as well.)

Comment: I deliberately didn't tell because ① that spoils the fun of searching and ② if one has trouble spotting the difference they should be given any possible opportunity to learn spotting such minute differences because this skill helps a lot with computers ;-)